# How to do count on a field in SQL which allows count of zero on a specific group?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Here's some psudo-content from a table in database.

```
type  approved
A     true
A     true
B     true
C     false
```

What I intend to get for result is:

```
A 2
B 1
C 0
```

which calculates the number of each type that is approved. But if I execute SQL `select count(approved) from table where approved = true`, it will only show

```
A 2
B 1
```

What could I do to show the **C 0**, too? Many thanks!

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY, which may well prove problematic further down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.

```
select type, sum(case when approved = 'true' then 1 else 0 end) as total 
from table
group by type
```

Answer (score 0):

Or instead of case you can use nullif:

```
select
    type,
    count(nullif(approved, false)) as true_count
from YourTable
group by type;
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-conditional.html